# What exactly happens when I pipe an output?

Tags: bash

> A pipe in Bash takes the standard output of one process and passes it
> as standard input into another process. Bash scripts support
> positional arguments that can be passed in at the command line.

I am working with Linux commands and pipes have always come up. What does it mean to pipe the standard output of one process? I understand that the output will be sent to the next command in the pipeline but how? How exactly does it happen? Why does variables created in a sub shell not be piped?

Comment: `Why does variables created in a sub shell not be piped?` I do not understand the question. Variables are never "piped", you can only pipe bytes. Variables are abstract. You can pipe the content of the variable, or the variable name, or both, both are bytes. Note that your questions are very vague - `How exactly does it happen?` - "Exactly" your processor executes the instruction. There are endless resources on the net how pipes are implemented. Have you tried reading them?

Comment: @KamilCuk Can I pipe contents of a variable? Can you include this in your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does it mean to pipe the standard output of one process?

It means to execute `pipe` system call. Then, `fork` one process, execute `dup2` system call to duplicate file descriptor representing standard output stream to one of the file descriptors returned by `pipe`. Then, `fork` the second process, do the same `dup2` but with the standard output file descriptor and the other file descriptor returned by `pipe`.

> but how? How exactly does it happen?

Calling `write` system call from one process on one of the file descriptors returned by `pipe` system call, it executes a handler for the pipe, a kernel function, that takes the content of the buffer from userspace process and places it in a circular hold buffer.

When the other process executes `read` system call on the other file descriptors returned by `pipe` system call, the kernel function reads the element from the pipe circular hold buffer and copies data to the buffer given by the user, and advances the hold buffer.

> Can I pipe contents of a variable? Can you include this in your answer?

You can execute a process that `write`s the content of the variable to standard output and connect the process to a pipe. I.e. `echo "$var" |`.

Comment: The variable itself is stored inside bash process in some hashmap. `var will it be available if it is create in a sub shell?` I do not understand the sentence. If you ask if a variable set in a subshell will be visible by parent shell, then no. One of the most important security features in any operating system is that processes are separate. A subshell can't affect parent shell or any other process. `If i try to access the variable out side the sub shell it wont be accessible?` I do not understand. Post [MCVE]. I believe you might want to read  https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024